# Building a multi-tenant app for SharePoint Online O365

Tags: sharepoint, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, multi-tenant

I am attempting to build a multi-tenant application for Office 365 which focuses on SharePoint Online and authenticates through Azure using OAuth2. The problem is specific to SharePoint access via the Azure login, but is only found when using this API to authenticate using OAuth2.

Many of the mechanics of registering the application properly and setting up users in Azure and Office, while somewhat complex, are conquerable with the right about of time investment.

Even the basic OAuth2 protocol usage with Azure works relatively smoothly. However, I'm thwarted in making my application truly multi-tenant by virtue of SharePoint's 'resource' parameter. This apparently requires my application to know the end-user's root SharePoint site URL before they complete the login sequence. I can't see how that is possible. Someone please point me in the right direction.

Here is a sample of the actual login sequence:

```
GET /common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=5cb5e93b-57f5-4e09-97c5-e0d20661c59a
&redirect_uri=https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/
&response_type=code&prompt=login&state=D79E5777 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

When the user authenticates, this results in a call to the redirect provided that looks like this:

```
https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/?code=AAABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEq...{blah*3}
```

Great so far! The next step in the 3-legged authentication is a POST back to the /token endpoint to acquire the actual Bearer token to be used in all subsequent REST calls. This is just classic OAuth2...

```
POST /common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Accept: text/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

authorization_code
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

AAABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEq...{blah*3}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

5cb5e93b-57f5-4e09-97c5-e0d20661c59a
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

02{my little secret}I=
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="redirect_uri"

https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

and here's where it gets sticky. The 'resource' parameter is required, and must point to the user-specific endpoint that you want access to. For Exchange or Azure, the endpoint is always the same. (`https://graph.windows.net` or `https://outlook.office365.com`) But SharePoint has a different endpoint for every tenancy. You haven't actually logged the user in yet, but already you need information about the user that you don't yet have..

If I deploy a version of my application that assumes 'contoso' as the tenant name (as above) then only users in the contoso tenancy will succeed using my app to read SharePoint data.  As soon as another user in fabrikam tries to use it, my `POST` to the `/token` endpoint will ask for permission to the wrong site... and there's the rub.

How can I detect the correct endpoint to `POST` to the `/token` endpoint prior to the user actually logging in? Is there some hidden information that is given to me that I can use? Is there some kind of discovery possible to detect the tenant's root SharePoint URL? Or better yet, is there an endpoint that I can pass as the resource that can be *representative* of the tenant's home (something like `https://office.microsoft.com/sharepoint`)? Then it could be potentially gleaned from the user_id JWT token returned. This would be similar to the other services, and quite simple for a client to manage. I don't see this, however.

Without a definitive answer to these questions, or workaround to these issues, I have to surmise that it is not possible to write a multi-tenant application that Authenticates into SharePoint Online O365... and that just doesn't seem right. Somebody please help!

Comment: Ah, finally. After many hours of research, experimentation, and development - I have stumbled on a solution! This is an undocumented 'feature' of the Azure / O365 APIs, so I want to make sure everyone who is interested in this topic discovers the key: Apparently authenticating to the Azure endpoint with the resource "https://api.office.com/discovery/" yields a CODE that can be used several times in the POST to /token step - allowing you to make a REST call to "discovery/v1.0/me/services" and iterate through the results, acquiring tokens for each one with the SAME CODE value. You're welcome :)

Comment: In retrospective: [http://yazezo.com/2013/10/how-to-setup-saas-cloud-multi-tenant.html](How to setup a SaaS cloud? Multi-tenant, CRM 2011, Outlook2010)

Answer (score 6):

I want to add detail to the solution mentioned briefly in my comment above - This will be important to anyone developing multi-tenant applications in Office 365, especially if the application will ever access SharePoint sites including OneDrive.

The procedure here is a little non-standard from the OAuth 2.0 perspective, but makes some sense in the multi-tenant world. The key is re-using the first CODE returned from Azure. Follow me here:

First we follow the standard OAuth authentication steps:

```
GET /common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=5cb5e93b-57f5-4e09-97c5-e0d20661c59a
&redirect_uri=https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/
&response_type=code&prompt=login&state=D79E5777 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This redirects to the Azure login page where the user logs in. If successful, Azure then calls back to your endpoint with a code:

```
https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/?code=AAABAAAA...{ONE-CODE-To-RULE-THEM-ALL}xyz
```

Now we POST back to the `/token` endpoint to acquire the actual Bearer token to be used in subsequent REST calls. Again, this is just classic OAuth2... but watch how we use the `/Discovery` endpoint as the resource - instead of any of the endpoints we will actually be using to gather data. Also, we ask for `UserProfile.Read` scope.

```
POST /common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Accept: text/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

authorization_code
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

AAABAAAA...{ONE-CODE-To-RULE-THEM-ALL}xyz
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

5cb5e93b-57f5-4e09-97c5-e0d20661c59a
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

02{my little secret}I=
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="redirect_uri"

https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scope"

UserProfile.Read
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://api.office.com/discovery/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

The response to this POST will contain an `access-token` that can be used to make REST calls to the `/discovery` endpoint.

```
{
    "refresh-token":  "AAABsvRw-mAAWHr8XOY2lVOKZNLJ{BAR}xkSAA", 
    "resource": "https://api.office.com/discovery/", 
    "pwd_exp": "3062796", 
    "pwd_url": "https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ChangePassword.aspx", 
    "expires_in": "3599", 
    "access-token": "ey_0_J0eXAiOiJjsp6PpUhSjpXlm0{F00}-j0aLiFg", 
    "scope": "Contacts.Read", 
    "token-type": "Bearer", 
    "not_before": "1422385173", 
    "expires_on": "1422389073"
}
```

Now, using this `access-token`, query the `/Services` endpoint to find out what else is available in Office 365 for this user.

```
GET /discovery/v1.0/me/services HTTP/1.1
Host: api.office.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5D
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Authorization"

Bearer ey_0_J0eXAiOiJjsp6PpUhSjpXlm0{F00}-j0aLiFg
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5D
```

The result will include an array of Service structures, describing the various endpoints and capabilities of each endpoint.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/$metadata#allServices",
    "value": [
        {
            "capability": "MyFiles",
            "entityKey": "MyFiles@O365_SHAREPOINT",
            "providerId": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
            "serviceEndpointUri": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me",
            "serviceId": "O365_SHAREPOINT",
            "serviceName": "Office 365 SharePoint",
            "serviceResourceId": "https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/"
        },
        {
            "capability": "RootSite",
            "entityKey": "RootSite@O365_SHAREPOINT",
            "providerId": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
            "serviceEndpointUri": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api",
            "serviceId": "O365_SHAREPOINT",
            "serviceName": "Office 365 SharePoint",
            "serviceResourceId": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"
        },
        {
            "capability": "Contacts",
            "entityKey": "Contacts@O365_EXCHANGE",
            "providerId": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
            "serviceEndpointUri": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0",
            "serviceId": "O365_EXCHANGE",
            "serviceName": "Office 365 Exchange",
            "serviceResourceId": "https://outlook.office365.com/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now comes the tricky part... At this point, we know the endpoints that we really want to authenticate to - some of which are tenant-specific. Normally you'd think we need to play the OAuth2 dance all over again with each of these endpoints.  But in this case, we can cheat a little - and simply POST the same CODE that we originally received from Azure - using the same HTTP request above, only altering the `resource` and the `scope` fields using the `serviceResourceId` and `capability` from the Service structure above. Like this:

```
POST /common/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.windows.net
Accept: text/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="grant_type"

authorization_code
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

AAABAAAA...{ONE-CODE-To-RULE-THEM-ALL}xyz
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_id"

5cb5e93b-57f5-4e09-97c5-e0d20661c59a
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="client_secret"

02{my little secret}I=
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="redirect_uri"

https://myappdomain.com/v1/oauth2_redirect/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scope"

MyFiles.Read
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

then do the same for the other two:

```
...
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scope"

RootSite.Read
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://contoso.sharepoint.com/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

and

```
...
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="scope"

Contacts.Read
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="resource"

https://outlook.office365.com/
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

All three of these calls will result in a response like the first POST above, providing you with a refresh-token and an access-token for each of the respective endpoints.  All of this for the price of only a single user authentication. :)

Viola! Mystery solved - you CAN write multi-tenant applications for O365. :)

Comment: Genius. Thanks! It has been the most horrible auth process I've ever dealt with. Glad I found this.

Comment: "It has been the most horrible auth process I've ever dealt with" - Hear hear! +1

Comment: Nice work! :) - But be cautious, there will probably be a time-limit on how long this CODE works.

Comment: Nils was right - here's the delta:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-breaking-changes#october-2018