# Office 365 unified API (preview) requests 401 error

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, onedrive, office365api

I'm trying to make some intersting things with Office 365 unified API (preview) and stuck on the moment with authorization. 
I made app with all permissions that I need 
[image]

I'm trying to log in users with URL
"https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/"

Evething works well.

I even can get access_token with all scopes by request to https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token.

[image]

BUT! I have problem, I cant get any information about user and cant get his files.

I tried to make requests like this:
[image]

I always just get HTTP status 401 Unauthorized.

What am I doing wrong?

***ALSO***
Question about possibilities with unified API. My target is to upload large files (up to 1GB). Is it possible with unified API? I can't find anything in documentation, but I found that it is not possible with OneDrive for Business API (max file size is 100MB).

Comment: Can you add more info about the specific scopes that you are adding? For accessing user's info User.Read is needed (at the minimum). To access user's files you need Files.Read.

Right now you won't be able to upload large files, that capability is coming soon.

Comment: I tried to add ALL scopes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Kardanov, Can you tell me if the following link works for you?
https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fbeta%2Fme%2Ffiles

Comment: Hi Kardanov - are the new permissions that you selected showing up in the access token?  The permissions you need are Files.Read (per Yina) and User.Read (Sign in and read user profile).  Is this problem solved or still active?

Comment: Dan, Shawn: seeing the same error. In the JSON I have "scope": "MyFiles.Read MyFiles.Write Userprofile.Read" I've tried every combination of checkboxes I either get the consent failure or I succeed but I can't seem to get a token that works for either the unified API or the SharePoint Online API. Is there documentation anywhere that simply says "to write with the sharepoint api add this app and check this box?" Because that would be a HUGE help: I've spent hours today just trying to figure out what magic combination of permissions will give me the things I need.

Comment: I've tried both the SharePoint 1.0 and 2.0 endpoints: both give me "Invalid audience" errors. Tried switching to the universal api: that gives me 401 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So struggled with the exact same problem earlier today: always got 401 Unauthorized or other errors. Then I ran across this answer: [Building a multi-tenant app for SharePoint Online O365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303590/building-a-multi-tenant-app-for-sharepoint-online-o365)

That was it: it is extremely counter-intuitive but the answer was that after getting a token for the discovery URL and performing the service discovery you need to fetch the token for each serviceResourceId you want to call. There are two hugely important points here that almost 8 hours of reading documentation do not make blatantly clear.

**EVERY SERVICE RESOURCE ID HAS A DIFFERENT TOKEN**

The first point is very confusing: I'm assuming its done this way because individual tenant apps are run on separate clusters and Microsoft has opted not to have a single authority service. Every single other implementation that does multi-tenant (for example, the Google Apps implementation) gives you a single token that wraps ALL your permissions into a single ball.

**YOU CAN CALL THE TOKEN RETRIEVAL SERVICE MULTIPLE TIMES WITH THE SAME CODE**

This is **INCREDIBLY** counter-intuitive (I'm using bold caps on purpose). There are simply no other OAuth2 services anywhere else on the Internet (and I've personally written code for easily 30 OAuth2 implementations) where you can call the token retrieval service multiple times with the same code and not receive an error. This goes completely against all default expectations and it is a major documentation failure that its not more clearly spelled out as a deviation from standard practice.

I'll say that again: no where else on the entire Internet can you actually use the same OAuth2 code more than once to retrieve an access token. This is something that should be called out PROMINENTLY on the documentation and simply isn't.

If you continue to have this problem you should do this with the OAuth2 code returned:

1. Get an access token token using the code and adding the request parameter "resource" = "https://api.office.com/discovery/" (the closing slash is important)
2. Call the url https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/services" using the Authorization header set to the token received in step #1. This will return a JSON object, with a ***value*** field. The value field will be an array of services that this code will return access tokens for. Each object in the value array will have a serviceResourceId property.
3. For each object you will have to get another access token using the SAME code you used in step #1 but with the resource set to the serviceResourceId.

The code from step #3 will actually grant you access to the tenant endpoint you want.
3.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!

Comment: As a side note, as there is probably some common denominator there although I'm talking of on-prem, is that on ASP.NET you can do the same as by default it doesn't guard against replay attacks. You need to specifically enable Token Replay Detection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161103(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the "Accept" header to "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal".  odata.metadata=none does not appear in the list of supported MIME types for the Unified API.

The supported type(s) as returned in Fiddler
'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=minimal, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatible=false, application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=false;IEEE754Compatib...' do not match any of the acceptable MIME types 'application/json; odata=verbose'