# Office 365 GetByteArrayAsync

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I'm stuck with diZerega's image file handler [example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2015/09/20/building-file-handler-add-ins-for-office-365/).

A similar example was also uploaded by Dorrene Brown on [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/GPX-FileHandler)

1.-The solution is provided for a multi tenant environment but no documentation highlights if you must set the multi tenant environment on true in the azure configuration portal, is it a must configuration step or an optional?

2.-I don't understand which specific kind of token I must get to execute the
function *httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync* and have the image as byte-array from SharePoint online, is this bound to the access token which you only get when you do the overload with AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken, clientCredential, **resource**) or does the overload with only refreshToken and clientCredentials suffice?

3.- At the moment I receive an access token with the overload of refreshToken and clientCredentials and when I try to get the image I keep getting the 401 error not authorized.

```
 var imgBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("https://MyDev.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/9f8ea500aea44c56837ba5bb5b3287a1/contents?access_token=123..");
```

2,3 Solved- As I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640963/office-365-unified-api-preview-requests-401-error) I got another time the access token but this time with AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(result.RefreshToken, clientCredential, **resource**); and the 401 error vanished. Still point number 1 is still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution is provided for a multi tenant environment but no documentation highlights if you must set the multi tenant environment on true in the azure configuration portal, is it a must configuration step or an optional?

For the multi-tenant app, it is a must configuration to set the multi-tenant to true.

[image]